# gnuplot conditional plotting: plot col A:col B if col C == x

Tags: gnuplot

How can I do this in gnuplot:

```
plot "test.csv" using 1:2 if value_in_column_3 == 80.0
```

It should only select those rows where column 3 == 80.0 and ignore all other rows (It should not plot a 0 for the other rows, simply ignore them)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Consider the following dataset (`1.dat`),

```
1 0.8 0
2 0.6 0
3 0.9 1
4 1.1 0
5 0.7 0
6 0.6 1
```

where we want to plot the first two columns only when the third one equals zero. Then you can try this:

```
plot '1.dat' using 1:($3==0?$2:1/0)
```

(Credit to [markjoe](http://old.nabble.com/Conditional-plotting-td23893745.html) on Gnuplot mailing-list.)

Comment: Note that since `1/0` is an invalid value, this will cause problems if one chooses to plot `lines` or `linespoints`; this is discussed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11187691/gnuplot-conditional-plotting-2-15-2-1-0-with-lines

Comment: How does this work?  I get it except for the 1/0 part.

Comment: @sdaau, there is a simple gnuplot-native workaround. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54475591/7295599

Comment: Using `NaN` in place of `1/0` is better.

Answer (score 21):

Case where one wants to plot conditionally on another column containing text:

data

```
1 0.8 a
2 0.6 a
3 0.9 a
1 2.1 b
2 1.7 b
3 1.6 b
```

code

```
set terminal postscript color
set xrange [0:4]
set yrange [0:3]
plot "1.dat" using 1:(stringcolumn(3) eq "a"? $2:1/0) title "a" lc rgb "blue" ,\
  "" using 1:(stringcolumn(3) eq "b"? $2:1/0) title "b" lc rgb "red"
```

command

```
gnuplot < 1.par > 1.ps
```

Answer (score 7):

As chl says above, the only way to do this in gnuplot is rather hacky: you have to use gnuplot's terniary ?: operator to generate a numerical error on the points you want to filter out of your dataset.

I may be biased here as I'm an author on the project, but you may want to have a look at Pyxplot http://www.pyxplot.org.uk (also free and open source), written by a group of gnuplot users who were a bit fed up with hacky syntax like this.

Its syntax is very similar to gnuplot, but with extensions. For what you want, you can specify a "select criterion" in the plot command, and points are only included if it tests True. See http://pyxplot.org.uk/current/doc/html/sec-select_modifier.html for more information.

Comment: Rather than using 1/0, you can just use NaN (Not a Number), which has exactly the same effect but seems more aesthetically pleasing.

Answer (score 7):

Another hack would be to use a shell command like `awk`:

```
plot "< awk '$3==80.0 { print $1, $2 }' test.csv" using 1:2
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are calling a script, use `column(2)` instead of `$2`

```
plot "1.dat" using 1:(stringcolumn(3) eq "a"? column(2):1/0) title "a" lc rgb "blue" ,\
  "" using 1:(stringcolumn(3) eq "b"? column(2):1/0) title "b" lc rgb "red"
```