# Gnuplot plotting data from a file up to some row

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I have data in some text file which has let's say 10000 rows and 2 columns. I know that I can plot it easily by `plot "filename.txt" using 1:2 with lines` . What I want is however just plotting let's say the rows from 1000 to 2000 or any other reasonable selection. Is it possible to do that easily? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: maybe this can help you too:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6564561/gnuplot-conditional-plotting-plot-col-acol-b-if-col-c-x

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Simpler:

```
plot "<(sed -n '1000,2000p' filename.txt)" using 1:2 with lines
```

Comment: Is there any nice online stuff where I can learn this kind of small awesome tricks. Thanks for the reply btw.

Comment: Following answer is a better option!

Answer (score 102):

It appears that the ["every" command](http://lowrank.net/gnuplot/datafile2-e.html#7.6) in gnuplot is what you're looking for:

```
plot "filename.txt" every ::1000::2000 using 1:2 with lines
```

Alternatively, pre-process your file to select the rows in which you are interested.  For example, using awk:

```
awk "NR>=1000 && NR<=2000" filename.txt > processed.txt
```

Then use the resulting "processed.txt" in your existing gnuplot command/script.

Comment: If you are on linux or mac osx, you should have awk already (it is part of the standard *nix toolset, like sed and grep).  I would start by running the above command as a pre-processing step (before launching gnuplot), which will create a new data file "processed.txt" while leaving your existing file unharmed.  You should then use "processed.txt" in place of "filename.txt" in your plotting commands.  The manual for awk can be found here: http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html

Answer (score 9):

You can probably cut out the reliance on an external utility (If your system doesn't have them installed for example) using the pseudo-column 0.

see `help plot datafile using pseudocolumn`

Try something like:

```
LINEMIN=1000
LINEMAX=2000

#create a function that accepts linenumber as first arg
#an returns second arg if linenumber in the given range.
InRange(x,y)=((x>=LINEMIN) ? ((x<=LINEMAX) ? y:1/0) : 1/0)

plot "filename.txt" using (InRange($0,$1)):2 with lines
```

(tested on Gnuplot 4.4.2, Linux)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend some commandline tools like `sed`, `grep` or `bash`. In your example

```
head -n 2000 ./file.data > temp.data
```

and

```
tail -n 1000 temp.data > temp2.data
```

might work. But haven't tested if such large numbers work with head and tail.

Comment: This combined with the first answer helped me: plot "<(tail -n 90 filename.txt)" ... to read most recent 90 lines of a dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Gnuplot ignores NaN values. This works for me for a specified range of the x coordinate. Not sure how to specify row range though.

```
cutoff(c1,c2,xmin,xmax) = (c1>=xmin)*(c1<=xmax) ? c2 : NaN
plot "data.txt" u 1:(cutoff(($1),($2),1000,2000))
```