# Scripting with gnuplot--where sed 

Tags: bash, scripting, sed, gnuplot

So I'm looking for some quick-and-dirty solution.

**The problem:**

I am trying to plot a specific section of a data file with gnuplot.  This is fine.  The basic line goes something like

```
plot "<(sed -n '1,100p' pointsandstuff.dat)" u 1:log($4**2+$5**2) notitle
```

This works just fine.  The next step I want is to include in my title another part of the data, namely the data entry $3 (which for the points listed is identical, so I can parse it from anywhere).  I run into problem because, while plot seems fine, I can't seem to feed regex info into 'title'.  An example of something that *doesn't* work"

```
plot "<(sed -n '1,100p' pointsandstuff.dat)" u 1:log($4**2+$5**2) title "<(sed -n '1,1p' pointsandstuff.dat)"
```

(This would spit out a whole data line, in theory, though in practice I just get the title "<(sed...")

I tried attacking this with a bash script, but the '$'s that I use throw the bash script into a tizzy:

```
#!/bin/bash


STRING=$(echo|sed -n '25001,25001p' pointsandstuff.dat)
echo $STRING


 gnuplot -persist << EOF
 set xrange[:] noreverse nowriteback
 set yrange[:] noreverse nowriteback

 eval "plot "<(sed -n '25001,30000p' pointsandstuff.dat)" u 1:log($4**2+$5**2) title $STRING


EOF
```

Bash won't know what to do with '$4' and '$5'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha, thanks all.  Have come up with a few solutions by now--the simplest being just escaping those $s from before (which I mistakenly thought gnuplot disliked...).  To whit:

```
STRING=$(echo|sed -n '1,1p' spointsandstuff.dat)
echo $STRING


 gnuplot -persist << EOF
 set xrange[:] noreverse nowriteback
 set yrange[:] noreverse nowriteback

 eval "plot "<(sed -n '1,100p' pointsandstuff.dat)" u 1:(log(\$4**2+\$5**2)) title '$STRING'
 !gv diag_spec.eps &

EOF
```

Thanks all, though--it's been a good excuse to play with this stuff...here's hoping that, if any poor soul sees this script later, it might be a bit easier on them.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be attempting process substitution, but the double quotes stop it working in the first case and you need a command substitution in the second case.

You have:

```
plot "<(sed -n '1,100p' pointsandstuff.dat)" u 1:log($4**2+$5**2) \
      title "<(sed -n '1,1p' pointsandstuff.dat)"
```

You need:

```
plot <(sed -n '1,100p' pointsandstuff.dat) u 1:log($4**2+$5**2) \
      title "$(sed -n '1,1p' pointsandstuff.dat)"
```

The double quotes in the second case might not be strictly necessary, but you won't go wrong with them present.

- Process substitution generates a file name and feeds the output of the nested command into that file; the command thinks it is reading a file (because it is reading a file).
- Command substitution captures the output of the nested command in a string and passes that string to the command (when it is used as an argument to a command, as here).

Comment: Thanks Jonathan!  But it seems that gnuplot (where this is being piped via this EOF block) does not evaluating that first sed phrase as anything but a string (i.e., if you take away the double quotes, it will give erros).  It's as if there's some eval-like behavior native to the plot command in gnuplot.

Comment: One thing that springs to mind is that it might be more sensible to do all data manipulation outside the gnuplot-piped block.  Is there a way to do this without just rewriting a bunch of data files (i.e, a way to manipulate the data outside the gnuplot piped block in a gnuplot friendly manner without ever writing to disk?)

Comment: For debugging, it is easier if you have separate steps.  For example, `title=$(sed 1q pointsandstuff.dat)` allows you to print `$title` before it is given to `plot`.  (The use of `1q` instead `-n 1p` means that `sed` does not read the whole file, which can improve performance if the file can be big.)  You might need to look at single quotes around the `1:log($4**2+$5**2)` argument, since without quotes, the shell will expand `$4` and `$5` (quite probably to empty strings).

Comment: I've not looked at the argument conventions for `plot`, but there's probably a way, such as `sed 100q pointsandstuff.dat | plot - u '1:log($4**2+$5**2)' title "$title"`, to feed the output of `sed` into `plot` with a pipe not using process redirection.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of the question is a little hazy, but it looks like you want to plot the first 100 lines -- This is quite easy to do:

```
plot '< head -100 datafile.dat' u  ....
```

Of course, you can use `sed` if you wish (or `awk` or ...).  A gnuplot only solution might look like this:

```
plot 'datafile.dat' u ($0 > 100? 1/0:$1):(log($4**2+$5**2))
```

Or like this (which is more simple for regular selections):

```
plot 'datafile.dat' every ::25001::30000 u 1:(log($4**2+$5**2)
```

and explained in more detail in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881747/how-to-plot-specific-rows-in-gnuplot/10882104#10882104).

Now, if you want the title to come from the datafile, you can parse it out using gnuplot's `backtic substitution`:

```
plot ... title "`head -1 datafile.dat | awk '{print $3}'`"
```

which is essentially the same as gnuplot's system command:

```
plot ... title system("head -1 datafile.dat | awk '{print $3}'")
```

but in this case, you *might* be able to use the `columnhead` function:

```
plot ... title columnhead(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the records, instead of `$4` or `$5` you could write `column(4)` and `column(5)` and you don't have to think about escaping `$` or not.
Furthermore, there is no need for `sed`, `awk`, `head` or other system calls which make the script platform dependent.

Here is a platform-independent *gnuplot-only* solution:

OP does not show example data, but what I understood from the description that the part of the data which should be plotted contains an identical text in column 3.
Note that row index is zero-based in gnuplot. The construct `'+' u ... every ::0::0` is just one way of many ways to [plot a single data point](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19452516/7295599), and here it is just used for the title which has been extracted in the preceding plot command.

By the way, if OP wanted to plot only data which is defined by the text in column 3 (which is not clear from the question), e.g. in the example below `PartB` data, there would be another way, where you even don't have to specify the row indices `M` and `N` because gnuplot could simply filter the `PartB` data.

**Data:** `SO12223772.dat`

```
 1   2   PartA   11   12
 2   2   PartA   21   22
 3   1   PartA   31   32
 4   2   PartA   41   42
 5   2   PartA   51   52
 6   2   PartA   61   62
 7   2   PartB   71   72
 8   2   PartB   81   82
 9   2   PartB   91   92
10   2   PartB  101  102
11   2   PartB  111  112
12   2   PartC  121  122
13   2   PartC  131  132
14   2   PartC  141  142
```

**Script:** (works with gnuplot>=4.4.0, March 2010)

```
### plotting only a part of data and extracting title from a column
reset 

FILE = "SO12223772.dat"

M =  6   # row index 0-based
N = 10
set style line 1 pt 7 lc rgb "blue"
set key top left
f(col1,col2) = log(column(col1)**2+column(col2)**2)

plot FILE u 1:(f(4,5)) w lp ls 1 lc rgb "grey" ti "full data", \
       '' u 1:(myTitle=strcol(3),f(4,5)) every ::M::N w lp ls 1 notitle, \
      '+' u 1:(1/0) every ::0::0 w lp ls 1 ti myTitle
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]