# Regular expression using awk for forcing data into gnuplot format

Tags: regex, awk, gnuplot

I'm relay struggling to get from this:

```
Wed Sep 24 09:18:01 BST 2014 -- temp=51.9'C -- message from script /usr/src/scripts/wifi_test_2.sh
```

To this for input into gnuplot format:

```
09:18:01 51.9
```

Using regular expression and [awk](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/gawk/gawk_5.html#SEC25)

1) I can recognize the "**temp=**" using `/temp=/` but how can I print out 4 characters after the = sign?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using GNU awk for gensub():

```
$ awk '{print $4, gensub(/.*temp=([0-9.]+).*/,"\\1","")}' file
09:18:01 51.9
```

With other awks use match() and substr():

```
$ awk '{print $4, substr($0,match($0,/temp=[0-9.]+/)+5,RLENGTH-5)}' file
09:18:01 51.9
```

With sed:

```
$ sed -r 's/.*(..:..:..).*temp=([0-9.]+).*/\1 \2/' file
09:18:01 51.9
```

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you try `sed`,

```
$ sed -r 's/.*([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}).*temp=([0-9.]+).*/\1 \2/g' file
09:18:01 51.9
```

If this your actual input then you may try the below awk command,

```
$ awk -F"[ =']" '{print $4,$9}' file
09:18:01 51.9
```

Comment: because I didn't know about it. Thank you very much, that worked from the command line.

Comment: **sed -r 's/.*([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}).*temp=([0-9.]+).*/\1 \2/g' /var/log/rebootlogfile.log** works from the command line, but  when I do **plot "<sed -r -n  's/.*([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}).*temp=([0-9.]+).*/\1 \2/p' /var/log/rebootlogfile.log" using 1:2**  using gnuplot it doesn't work. any ideas?

Comment: put the sed command inside `()` like `plot "<(sed -n 'regex' file)"` see http://stackoverflow.com/a/12223810/3297613

Comment: I'm trying to strip things down and hopfully get something working, so i did this: **plot "<(sed -r -n  's/.*temp=([0-9.]+).*/\1/p' /var/log/rebootlogfile.log)"** But I get **bad data on line one** Command line gives me a single column of "xx.x" which should work in gnuplot

Answer (score 0):

Although it's an old question... Why using awk or sed? Why not using gnuplot? With this you are *platform-independent*.

**Data:** `SO26013762.dat`

```
Wed Sep 24 09:18:01 BST 2014 -- temp=51.9'C -- message from script /usr/src/scripts/wifi_test_2.sh
Wed Sep 24 10:19:02 BST 2014 -- temp=53.1'C -- message from script /usr/src/scripts/wifi_test_2.sh
Wed Sep 24 11:20:03 BST 2014 -- temp=55.2'C -- message from script /usr/src/scripts/wifi_test_2.sh
```

**Script:** (works with gnuplot>=4.4.0, March 2010)

```
### extract numbers from special column
reset

FILE = "SO26013762.dat"

set xdata time
set timefmt "%H:%M:%S"
set format x "%H:%M"
set grid x
set grid y

# extract number between given characters
getNumber(col,c1,c2) = (s=strcol(col), real(s[strstrt(s,c1)+1:strstrt(s,c2)-1]))

plot FILE u (timecolumn(4)):(getNumber(8,'=',"'")) w lp pt 7 notitle
### end of script
```

**Result:** (created with gnuplot 4.6.0)

[image]