# gnuplot X and Y values in separate lines

Tags: date, gnuplot

I'm trying to `gnuplot` a data set like this

```
Di 4. Dez 19:10:09 CET 2012
Garbage
 description: 10.5  description2: 22.3
Mi 5. Dez 01:51:15 CET 2012
Garbage
 description: 10.5  description2: 22.4
```

Those 3-line-blocks repeat several times. I want to use the time from line 1,4,7 etc. to provide the date (as X-value) for the actual data in lines 3,6,9 etc. (as Y-values) every other column. In the end the plot should be composed by the following lines (in [X,Y]-format) [1,3],[1,6],[1,9],[4,3],[4,6],[4,9] etc.
From what I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881747/how-to-plot-specific-rows-in-gnuplot) it's possible to use [every](https://www.physics.iitm.ac.in/~sanoop/linux_files/gnuplot-every.html) but I can't figure out how.

EDIT: I solved the timefmt issue below thanks to user1901493's tip. Disregard the issue below (didn't delete it there for reference).

A test with just the first line with `set timefmt "%d %b %H:%M:%S"` and `using 2:6` doesn't work either, complaining about a bad month abbreviation. This [should work](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node274.html) though. This could be part of the problem though.

Answer (score 1):

The bad month abbreviation might come from the fact that gnuplot does not understand the german Dez. abbreviation, so try again with dec instead of Dez.

Secondly, I think gnuplot only uses data in columns, so a file with your format:

```
x1
...
y1 z1
x2
...
y2 z2
```

might not work at all. I suggest that you rearrange your data file with something like grep so that your datafile looks like this:

```
x1 y1 z1
x2 y2 z2
```

Comment: ah I checked with `date +%b` and assumed gnuplot would use `date` internally as well. Thanks for the heads up. The second part I don't want to agree with...yet ;P