# Plotting an arbitrary set of lines inside a "do for" in gnuplot

Tags: loops, animation, gnuplot

I have data collected in one two column file, and I want to animate this data. The data file has the points in sets of 100 points, one after the other something like this:

```
...
98 0.34
99 .036
100 .40
1 .01
2 .05
...
```

and I am looking to a gnuplot algorithm that would look like this:

```
reset
set term gif animate
set output "animate.gif"

do for [i=0:49]{
   plot "<(sed -n 'i*100+1,(i+1)*100p' data.dat)" using 1:2 with lines
}
set output
set term x11
```

How can I make the `i` change inside "plot ... lines"?

This question is inspired by this [other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9536582/gnuplot-plotting-data-from-a-file-up-to-some-row)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think i got it, because I'm getting what I want, I changed the line

```
plot "... lines
```

by

`plot "data.dat" every ::i*100+1::(i+1)*100 using 1:2`
and it seems to work well. The answer was also in the same link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9536582](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9536582/gnuplot-plotting-data-from-a-file-up-to-some-row)