# gnuplot stacked histogram overlapping

Tags: plot, gnuplot, histogram

I have the following two data files I want to plot using **gnuplot**.

*timings0.log:*

```
41420
32587
4082
4668
81
547
325
```

*timings1.log:*

```
41297
32393
4106
4720
75
502
266
```

They represent timings of different components of a piece of software, where each file is generated by an execution with a different configuration, and where each line in the files corresponds to a different component. I am using the *sed* commands to be able to extract specific lines in the timings files (following an approach suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9536582/gnuplot-plotting-data-from-a-file-up-to-some-row)), and be able to display plots where only some components appear. I want to display both sets of timings in the same plot, in a **stacked histogram** way.

Here is my current code:

```
set terminal svg size 500,500 enhanced font 'Times-Roman,14'

set key vertical maxrows 3

set style data histograms
set style histogram rowstacked title offset 0,-1 gap 1
set boxwidth 0.5 relative
set style fill solid 1.0

set xlabel offset 0,1
set xrange [-1:2]

set xtics 0,1
set xtics add ("1st Config"0)
set xtics add ("2nd Config"1)
set xtics add (""2)

set yrange [0:50000]
set ylabel "Time (ms)"
set ytics 0,5000,50000

set output "test.svg" 

plot newhistogram "0" lt 1, "<(sed '2!d' timings0.log)" notitle, "<(sed '3!d' timings0.log)" notitle, "<(sed '4!d' timings0.log)" notitle, "<(sed '5!d' timings0.log)" notitle,\
     newhistogram "1" lt 1, "<(sed '2!d' timings1.log)" t "Load", "<(sed '3!d' timings1.log)" t "Sort", "<(sed '4!d' timings1.log)" t "Calculation", "<(sed '5!d' timings1.log)" t "Cleanup"
```

The code works perfectly when I display only one histogram (corresponding to *timings0.log* for instance), but when running the above script to display both histograms, they **fail to spread out on the xaxis and they seem to overlap**. Here is the output of the above script:

[image]

There might be an obvious solution, but after numerous attempts and searching on several resources available online, I have failed to obtain the correct output. I am using gnuplot 5 patchlevel 3.

Thanks in advance, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `at`:

```
plot newhistogram at 0 lt 1, ...
     newhistogram at 1 lt 1, ...
```

I also get an error with `gap`, at least in gnuplot 4.6. It doesn't have an effect with `rowstacked` but you can use it *before* `offset`. The overall code:

```
set terminal svg size 500,500 enhanced font 'Times-Roman,14'

set key vertical maxrows 3

set style data histograms
set style histogram rowstacked
set boxwidth 0.5 relative
set style fill solid 1.0

set xlabel offset 0,1
set xrange [-1:2]

set xtics 0,1
set xtics add ("1st Config"0)
set xtics add ("2nd Config"1)
set xtics add (""2)

set yrange [0:50000]
set ylabel "Time (ms)"
set ytics 0,5000,50000

set output "test.svg"

plot newhistogram at 0 lt 1, "<(sed '2!d' timings0.log)" notitle, "<(sed '3!d' timings0.log)" notitle, "<(sed '4!d' timings0.log)" notitle, "<(sed '5!d' timings0.log)" notitle,\
     newhistogram at 1 lt 1, "<(sed '2!d' timings1.log)" t "Load", "<(sed '3!d' timings1.log)" t "Sort", "<(sed '4!d' timings1.log)" t "Calculation", "<(sed '5!d' timings1.log)" t "Cleanup"
```

Looks like this for me:

[image]