# Selecting a single row from a data file in gnuplot

Tags: plot, gnuplot, data-files

I have a data file with 100 columns and thousands of rows, but I want to be able to select one single row, and in that row, use the even columns as the inputs for the X-axis and the odd columns as inputs for the Y-axis for a plot. Is there any way I can do that in gnuplot?

Comment: Take a look at [Gnuplot plotting data from a file up to some row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9536582/gnuplot-plotting-data-from-a-file-up-to-some-row), it may help you to select the desired line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here the script I've done to plot a given line from a given data file with odd column as x-axis and even column as y-axis.

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot
set term pdf
set output "plot.pdf"

line_number=1
data_file="data.dat"

set xrange[0:10]
set yrange[0:10]

table_file="/tmp/gnuplot_tab.dat"
set table table_file

plot for[i=1:*:2] "<(sed -n '".line_number."p' ".data_file.")" u i:i+1
unset table
unset key
plot table_file
```

Let's explain this script:

First we specify the line number with `line_number` and the data filename with `data_file`. The effect of `set table table_file`is, as specified by gnuplot [documentation](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node267.html), the print of points' coordinates in the file ̀table_file`instead of ploting them with`plot`command.

The `plot for[i=1:*:2]` plots for each `i` beginning from `1`, ending when no more column can be ploted and incrementing by `2` at each iteration. The idea is to take the columns `i` (*i.e.* odd) and `i+1` (*i.e.* even) as coordinates (or use the inverse `i+1:i` to take even for x-axis and odd for y-axis).

The part `"<(sed -n '".line_number."p' ".data_file.")"` is inspired from [Gnuplot plotting data from a file up to some row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9536582/gnuplot-plotting-data-from-a-file-up-to-some-row) and selects the line you specified as a file. Since `set table` has been done, this `plot` command saves each coordinate to a new file. This is a trick to transform the line in a two column file.

Finally the script disable the ̀set table`to then plot the saved file`table_file`

I tested it with the following data file changing the line number from `1` to `2`:

```
10 10 9 9 8 8 7 7 6 6 5 5 4 4 3 3 2 2 1 1 0 0
0 10 1 9 2 8 3 7 4 6 5 5 6 4 7 3 8 2 9 1 10 0
```