# GNUPLOT - all points y value undefined for time series plot

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to plot time series data using GNUPLOT and have the following data in `no_int1_date.dat`(only a snippet):

```
1/25/20  0  1.0
1/26/20  1  0.9267715113341058
1/27/20  2  0.9015549457234168
1/28/20  3  0.9102921688940067
1/29/20  4  0.9434869898964108
1/30/20  5  0.9956757741755345
```

I wish to plot column 1 as x-axis (dates) with column 3 times a multiplier as y-axis (individuals). Column 2 contains the index or number of days. I am using the following lines in the source code:

```
set xdata time
set timefmt "%m/%d/%Y"
plot [100:370] "./data/no_int1_date.dat" u 1:($3*0.0639) w line lw 2 lc "red" title 'Individuals requiring hospitalization', \
     [100:370] "./data/no_int1_date.dat" u 1:($3*0.03) w line lw 2 lc "blue" title 'Individuals requiring intensive care'
```

Error on command `gnuplot -p hospital.gnuplot`:

```
plot [100:370] "./data/no_int1_date.dat" u 1:($3*0.0639) w line lw 2 lc "red" title 'Individuals requiring hospitalization',     [100:370] "./data/no_int1_date.dat" u 1:($3*0.03) w line lw 2 lc "blue" title 'Individuals requiring intensive care',     1/0 lw 2 lc "red" dt 2 title "Hospital capacity",     1/0 lw 2 lc "blue" dt 2 title "Intensive care capacity" 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         ^
"./src/hospital.gnuplot", line 14: all points y value undefined!
```

However on modifying the same lines in the source code to (commented out directives and changed column to index or number of days):

```
# set xdata time
# set timefmt "%m/%d/%Y"
plot [100:370] "./data/no_int1_date.dat" u 2:($3*0.0639) w line lw 2 lc "red" title 'Individuals requiring hospitalization', \
     [100:370] "./data/no_int1_date.dat" u 2:($3*0.03) w line lw 2 lc "blue" title 'Individuals requiring intensive care'
```

**Why am I getting an error on trying to plot the same data with the dates?**

Ubuntu 18.04, GNUPLOT 5.2 patchlevel 2

Comment: `[100:370]` - what does this specify? Also note that `%Y` is a 4-digit year, you really want year `20`, not `2020`?

Comment: I wished to plot data from lines 100 to 370 as can be seen in the figure's x-axis. Is this incorrect? This seems to be the piece of code that is causing the issue, you're right. I switched it up to `%y`. I don't mind `20` or `2020`. Same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error lies in the definition of the xrange. You specify x to be timedata in the format "month/day/year", but in the plot command the xrange is written as `[100:370]`, which doesn't match the format. I guess gnuplot is transforming these numbers to seconds from 01.01.1970 or whatever. None of your data points lies in this range, hence gnuplot can't plot anything.

You can specify the xrange in the same format as your time data:

`set xrange ["1/25/20":"1/30/20"]`

or

`plot ["1/25/20":"1/30/20"] "./data/no_int1_date.dat" ...`

EDIT: If you want to plot the lines 100 to 370, you can use the pseudo-column 0 as x axis: `plot [100:370] "data.dat" using 0:3`

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there any way to specify the lines I wish to plot from the datafile?

Comment: Sure, there are lots of ways to achieve that. I added one possibility to my answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9536582/gnuplot-plotting-data-from-a-file-up-to-some-row